# How to get CMutablePointer<SCNVector3> from SCNVector3[]?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to use SCNGeometrySource's `init(vertices: CMutablePointer<SCNVector3>, count: Int)` initializer, but I don't know how to make `CMutablePointer<SCNVector3>`.

In Objective-C, I would have used a C array, but I don't think a `SCNVector3[]` in Swift is laid out that way.

Comment: Try: `init(&vertices, yourCount)`.

Comment: "'SCNVector3[]' is not a subtype of '@lvalue $T1'"

Comment: how are your vertices declared?

Comment: `let vertices: SCNVector3[] = [ ... ]`

Comment: It compiles, but I don't think it works after all: http://cl.ly/image/1Y2h1t1b273P

Comment: how about: `NSData(bytes: &nums, length:  sizeof(UInt32[]) * nums.count)`

Comment: The size seems right. The problem is that the data isn't the contents of the array. It's different on each run, so it's probably some internal storage.

Comment: Final update! Apparently when constructing NSData you *should not* use the &, but when you are initializing SCNGeometrySource you *should* use the &. It appears to be a bug that the compiler doesn't warn you when you do it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `CMutablePointer<SCNVector3>` from `SCNVector3[]` with `&`:

```
var vertices: SCNVector3[] = [ ... ]
let geometrySource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: &vertices, count: vertices.count)
```

It's important that vertices is mutable (declared with 'var' instead of 'let').

(found thanks to Adam's nudging in the comments above... whose answer I'll accept if he writes one :)